# Writing requirement for specific Java (JRE) version

Tags: java

The system in which our application must run has a specific version of Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed and it may not be changed.

Therefore I have written a system requirement for my team, which we shall test later (before delivering the finished product). Can somebody confirm if my wording here is ok/nok? I'm mostly insecure about the JVM part because I don't really know the intricacies of how Java runs.

*RedactedApplicationName shall be able to run in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) with Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 1.8.0_241 64bit.*

Note: we follow the standard Volere Requirements Specification template.

Comment: The requirement is meant to communicate to the team some information. Why don't simply ask the developers if your statement encompasses what you mean to inform?

Answer (score 3):

I think [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-jdk-jre-jvm/) can help you out. The bottom line is this picture:

[image]

In your case, you can easily leave out the part about the Java Virtual Machine (**JVM**) since that is already present in Java Runtime Environment (**JRE**). Therefore, your requirement could read:

*RedactedApplicationName shall use Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 1.8.0_241 64bit.*

Comment: Oh right yes that makes sense, because I suppose there may be relevant Library Classes in that specific JRE version.